# Is the complex conjugate of a holomorphic function always the function of the conjugate argument?

Tags: complex-analysis

Imagine that $f(z)$ is holomorphic in some subsect of the complex plane. Is it true that 
$$
\bar{f}(z)=f(\bar{z})
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is false. Take for example $f(z)=iz$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Consider the function $f(z)=e^{iz}$ which is holomorphic.

$$f(z)=e^{iz}=e^{-y+ix}=e^{-y}(\cos x + i \sin x)$$

$$\bar {f(z)}= e^{-y}(\cos x - i \sin x)$$

$$ f(\bar z ) = e^{i(x-iy)}= e^y(\cos x +i\sin x)$$

As you notice they are different.